# C# Get first whole line after removing duplicate substrings

Tags: c#, linq

I have a file that contains many *duplicate substrings* and want to remove them and keep only the *first one* and write the entire line of the first substring in a richtextbox, in my code i get the following error:

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[System.String,System.

```
var FilePrefixes = File.ReadAllLines(FILE)
            .Select(line => line.Split(',')[0]);

var dupsubstrings= File.ReadAllLines(FILE)
    .Where(line => FilePrefixes.Count() > 1).Select(line => line.First());

richTextBox1.AppendText(dupsubstrings+ Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: And the error you get is....?

Comment: The error is a secret...`

Comment: @elgonzo - why did you rollback that good edit?

Comment: @DigiFriend, because M.esie has not explained the error itself. While the code itself has some issues, look very closely at my last comment. The error M.elsie is talking about might actually be a compiler error. Hence the rollback...

Comment: Do you want to remove the duplicate lines or any line that contains a substring that has appeared before? Later doesn't make much sense.

Comment: So? And how is that related to the code formatting? The OP is new to the platform and doesn't know how to properly format code. Don't revert a good edit just because.

Comment: That's not the whole error message...

Comment: Yes @Saket wanna remove any line that contains duplicate substring that has appeard before

Comment: Yes DigiFriend i'm  new to the platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `GroupBy` the substrings of the question and then take the `First` item form each grouping chunk:

```
 var distinctStrings = File
   .ReadLines(FILE)                          // No "All"
   .GroupBy(line => line.Split(',')[0],      // group by prefix
            (key, chunk) => chunk.First());  // take 1st ocurrence from each group

 // Join all distinct strings into one  
 richTextBox1.AppendText(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, distinctStrings));
```

Please, avoid `ReadAllLines` (reading *all* the lines and only then start processing them) and *double file opening* (`File.ReadAllLines(FILE)` then `File.ReadAllLines(FILE)`)

Comment: Got System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable`4[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]

Comment: @M.elsie: if you want finally join all `distinctStrings` into a final string and append the richedit - add `Join` (see my edit)

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing here:

```
.Select(line => line.First());
```

Is selecting the first character of each line. I expect that's not what you want to do, but to select the first line (as you say in your question).

To select the first line, change that `.Select` to:

```
.First();
```